# Do premiums count towards out of pocket maximum?

Tags: terminology, medical-billing, health-insurance

There are several terms to think about:

- `premium` - the monthly cost of a plan
- `deductible` - the amount you pay before your insurance kicks in
- `coinsurance` - the amount you pay after your insurance kicks in
- `copay` - also the amount you pay after your insurance kicks in
- `out-of-pocket maximum` - the amount you pay before your insurance pays for everything

Two questions:

1. Do you continue to pay your premium even after you've met your out-of-pocket maximum?
2. Does your premium count towards your deductible or out-of-pocket maximum?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). This question is too broad, since it may vary depending on the country you are in. Moreover, it is a financial one and not related to health as specified in the [help]. VTC

Answer (score 0):

From reading [another blog post](https://www.verywell.com/do-premiums-count-toward-your-deductible-1738443):

> Unfortunately, health insurance doesn’t work that way; `premiums` don’t count toward your `deductible`.

Also:

> After you’ve paid enough in `deductibles`, `copays`, and `coinsurance` to
>   have reached your `out-of-pocket maximum` each year, your health plan
>   begins to cover 100% of the cost of your care for the rest of the
>   year.
>
> You don’t have to pay any more cost-sharing that year. However, you
>   still have to pay your monthly `premiums` or your health insurance
>   policy will be canceled.

Comment: While this is true with every policy I've ever had, I don't believe there's anything preventing a company from writing policies with different rules. Insurance is a contract. The terms are whatever the contract says they are.